# To modify INDEX-MATCH which is not working

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Basically this is supposed to be a modified `INDEX/MATCH` formula but will depend on variables and headers on another workbook, as well as hopefully make it easier on the user by only requiring them to provide two parameters.

```
Option Compare Text
Function DATAFILL(ID_number, source_headerRow) As Variant
    ID_header_name = Cells.Item(1, ID_number.column).Value
    Dim wb As String, ws As String
    Dim ID_src As Range
'check if source_headerRow is an external workbook
    If source_headerRow Like "'" Then
        src = Split(source_headerRow.address(External:=True), "!")(0)
        wb = Replace(Split(src, "]")(0),"[","")
        ws = Split(src, "]")(1)
        id_col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ID_header_name, source, 0)
        Set ID_src = Workbooks(wb).Worksheets(ws).Range(Cells(1, id_col))
    Else
        Set ID_src = Range(Cells(1, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ID_header_name, source_headerRow, 0)))
    End If

    headername = "Shift" 'placeholder
    Set addr = Workbooks(wb).Range("A:Z")
    DATAFILL = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(addr, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ID_number, ID_src), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(headername, source_headerRow, 0))

End Function
```

I'm very new to VBA so I can't pinpoint exactly where I'm going wrong...
No matter what I do, I get `#VALUE!` error.

Or is there a way to make `INDEX/MATCH` *user* friendly without needing VBA/Macros?

Comment: [`OFFSET`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66) can be helpful.

Comment: can it be done using an array =((A:A=criteria1)*(B:B=criteria2)*(C:C)) where C is the value?

Comment: I can't see where `source` (in `src = Split(source.address(External:=True), "!")(0)`) is defined.  Could this be the problem?

Comment: @aucuparia oops sorry, i just changed the variable names for readability.. i edited the OP thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what line is give you the VALUE error. That would help.
Or is it in a specific cell?

You haven't defined "addr" variable type anywhere that I can see
and you don't have OPTION EXPLICIT at the top, so by default "addr" wil be a Variant data type.

It needs to be `Object` at minimum and preferably `Range`

You should add `Option Explicit` to the top of your module (above `Option Compare Text`) and recompile until you can fix all the errors (if there are more)